# When does an Entity show up in the collection of the Model

Tags: entity-framework

I use entity framework and have a set of users:

```
 public class DbModel : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

I add a User like so:

```
  User UserOne = new User();
  model.Users.Add( UserOne );
```

I request the users count:
      int userCount = model.Users.Count();

userCount is "0" I would expect "1". Adding DetectChanges doen't help.
After  "model.SaveChanges()" the Count = 1, but that is to late I need to combine the in memory stuff with the DB stuff for validation. Is there a way to do this?

SOLUTION

Using the answer of Erik Philips I wrote the following extension method for the DbSet

```
public static class DBSetExtentions
{
     public static IEnumerable<T> AllMembers<T>(
         this DbSet<T> target, 
         Func<T, bool> selection
         )  where T : class
    {
        return target.Local.Where(selection).Union(target.Where(selection));
    }
 }
```

it allows me to do selections an validations accross **all** entities like:

```
    private void ValidateEmail(ValidationDto validationDto)
    {

        int usersWithSameEmail =
            validationDto.Model.Users.AllMembers(
                x => x.EmailAddress.Equals( EmailAddress ) ).Count();

        if (usersWithSameEmail > 1)
        {
            validationDto.Result.Add(new ValidationResult("Email address is in use"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the client side of items (committed and uncomitted) to your data storage by using [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

```
var count = model.Users.Local.Count();
```

One caveat is that this is only the local representation of Users.  Meaning it could contain a partial amount of users from the database (changed and/or unchanged), and new users you've created and not saved.

[Interesting Article - Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 7: Local Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx)

Comment: sorry , but is term "client side of items" correct ? isn't it better to say items in memory or "currently being tracked by the context" ?

Comment: @mohsen.d Absolutely, this was an attempt to make it clear that when you query `Local` you are _not_ querying the Server/Database, but just the local/client/dbcontext collection.

Comment: thanks, I gues I can join the result form DB and Local using a LINQ Join, great help